# how to listen to touch events in iframe?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, touch-event

the ontouchmove does not work anymore when I clicked any contents inside the iframe, how would I make this work?

or are there any other ways to log the touch events while embed another web page?

Comment: is the iframe same origin?

Comment: it links to an external site :( from my research it looks like that is simply impossible, now I need to figure another way.

Comment: You would need to contact the external site and have them add CORS headers granting access for your domain, as well as script support for you to access from outside the iframe window. If they will not do that, then you can't. CORS is in place precisely to prevent this sort of thing. Even with CORS support, you will still need javascript within the iframe that makes data and events inside that window accessible outside of it, which you cannot inject externally.

Comment: Please be more specific about what you are trying to accomplish. There is likely a much simpler and better answer to your specific issue.

Comment: if you provide more context like sample js and html, the probability of a good answer will increase

Comment: I try to obtain the biometric of a user when browsing certain sites. But instead of building a replica of the site I wish to just get it from an existing site. I could also accomplish this by borrowing a model for other existing sites, but there may be higher fidelity if I can, say let the user browse Facebook, and track the biometrics, and say the experiment was done for user browsing facebook rather than some site I just made up in less than 2 hours.